# Есть ли альтернатива для вложенного subscribe?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Есть ли альтернатива для вложенного subsribe?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы сделать код более компактным.

```
this.modalService
        .modalWindow(`Точно удалить товар "${name}" ?`, '')
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.itemService.del(id).subscribe(
                        () => {
                            this.itemService.list().subscribe(
                                (res: any) => {
                                    this.items = res;
                                    this.modalService.dismissLoader();
                                },
                                () => {
                                    this.modalService.dismissLoader();
                                }
                            );
                        },
                        () => {
                            this.modalService.dismissLoader();
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    this.modalService.dismissLoader();
                }
            },
            () => {
                this.modalService.dismissLoader();
            }
        );
```

Comment: Просто используйте flatMap. Я бы привёл пример кода, но не могу текст с картинки скопировать. Выкладывайте код текстом - так всем будет удобнее)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил)